# Sorting key-value pairs after map function in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file, which contains IP packet headers in text format.

After the map function, each reduce method is called for a particular IP address. I want the values in a sorted order, but they are not sorted. The value is basically a line, in which there is timestamp. I want all the values in reduce to be sorted by timestamp.

Please help me where to do that sorting.

Comment: Can you provide some example info on the inputs to mapping as well as the inputs that you expect for reduce? It seems like you have not picked the keys correctly for your reducer since you could define the timestamp as the key or use a composite key of multiple fields (for example with streaming you can achieve this by setting stream.num.map.output.key.fields to the number of fields you wish to use as your key).

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop MapReduce has a feature called "Secondary Sort" which does what you want.

The book "[Hadoop the definitive guide](http://basj.es/hadoop)" has a pretty good chapter on the subject.